# removing words from a line output powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell command with below output, The command output shows the active NIC adapter and NIC adapter name differ in each machine. But what I am looking here is, in one server active NIC adapter is Local Area Connection and in another one it is Ethernet.This will differ in all VM's

```
PS C:\> netsh interface ipv4 show interface |where { $_ -match '\sconnected' -and $_ -notmatch 'loopback'}
     12           5        1500  connected     **Local Area Connection**
    PS C:\>
    PS C:\> netsh interface ipv4 show interface |where { $_ -match '\sconnected' -and $_ -notmatch 'loopback'}
     12           5        1500  connected     **Ethernet**
    PS C:\>
```

I want only the adapter name to be captured (eg: Local Area Connection\Ethernet etc).

Can anyone help me modifying the command so that I will get the NIC adapter name without any white space as output?

The output should be like below

```
Local Area Connection
Ethernet
Ethernet 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running this on a Windows 8 or Server 2012 or newer operating system you can use the `Get-NetAdapter` cmdlet instead to get the result you want:

```
Get-NetAdapter | Where {$_.Status -eq 'Up'} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

On an older OS you could try this, which splits the text for each interface by the word "connected" and it's trailing whitespace using the regex special character `\s` and then return the second item of that split:

```
$Interfaces = netsh interface ipv4 show interface | where { $_ -match '\sconnected' -and $_ -notmatch 'loopback'}

$Interfaces | ForEach-Object { 
    ($_ -Split 'connected\s+')[1]
}
```

Or here is another option that avoids using the `-split` operator and instead uses a regex lookbehind to match 'connected' followed by 5 spaces in the string before what we want to return:

```
$Interfaces = netsh interface ipv4 show interface | where { $_ -notmatch 'loopback'}

$Interfaces | ForEach-Object { 
    [regex]::matches($_, '(?<=connected\s{5})(.*)').value
}
```